# Error when trying to find an element using SELENIUM

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hopefully someone can help me out here.

My goal is to successfully connect to [this](https://creeper.banano.cc/) website using Python (Selenium + Chromedriver) and successfully search for an address in the search bar. Im struggling to manage to find the actual search bar itself using Selenium. The HTML code doesn't have an ID or NAME to distinguish it by, all it has is a class and when i search for the class, i get an error saying it cannot be found.

Hopefully this is an easy fix and im just being silly. Thanks a lot.

P.S First post - please drop some hints on what to change next time :)

CODE

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://creeper.banano.cc/")
search = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ValidatedSearch form-control form-control-lg ")
```

ERROR CODE

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ValidatedSearch form-control form-control-lg "}
```

[Python Code + HTML of Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNE1p.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Since you asked so nicely, I wanted to let you know to always put three backticks (```) on the line before and after code and the line before and after an error. Also, it's generally a good idea to paste the full traceback, not just the last line. Other than that this is better than most people's first question :P

Comment: Thanks so much! I honestly wasn't expecting this much feedback so quickly, learned more in the 9 hours whilst sleeping than I did by myself reading around!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ValidatedSearch form-control form-control-lg

is what are referred to as multiple class names.

In order to find the element we use css selector.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ValidatedSearch.form-control.form-control-lg")
```

Also don't use driver.find_element_by since they are depreciated instead import By and use that.

Comment: When i use this, i get an error stating that the By is not defined.

Comment: It's an import so you need to include it.

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Answer (score 0):

The error here is you have multiple class names in a function only expecting one. `ValidatedSearch`, `form-control`, and `form-control-lg` are different classes, since classes can't have spaces in them. So what you're looking for is this:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ValidatedSearch")
```

This targets the first tag in the `ValidatedSearch` class that it finds.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with

```
search = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ValidatedSearch")
search.send_keys("Hi My Name is Slicka Slicka Slim Shady")
```

I used one class. I would say Selenium iirc only requires a single class. Also Im not primarily a webdesigner but these frameworks that are all over today are pretty much add the additionals are annoying. When I create Selenium scripts I use xpaths more and more more. You may want to look into that